# How to parse an array that is in a json object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having issues drilling down into a json object that has an array in it. The issue I'm running into is that when I get inside that object it returns object Object.

My code looks like this:

```
(function(){
   var rivetAPI = "https://url";
   $.ajax({
          url:rivetAPI,
          type:"GET",
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(obj){
          //var myData = JSON.stringify(obj);

          $.each(obj.data, function(index, value){
             $('.data').text(value);
           })
      }
   });
})();
```

I'm keeping the URL private, but wanted to show that it's coming from a HTTPS just in case that might be part of the problem.

The JSON is formatted as such:

```
{ "data": [
  {
     "likes": 10,
     "imageURL": "url",
     "mediaThumbURL": "url",
     "mediaDisplayURL": null,
     "mediaOriginalURL": "url",
     "userProfilePictureURL": null,
     "externalLink": null,
     "description": "The sun was setting behind the mounted memorial to Kaiser Wilhelm I.  (30 May 2015)",
     "mediaType": "Photo",
     "caption": "Sunset behind the memorial to Wilhelm I, Koblenz, Germany",
     "latitude": 50.364437,
     "longitude": 7.605915,
     "mediaID": "e9908afe-c9e1-11e5-829e-22000ae606bd",
     "userName": null,
     "googlePlaceId": "ChIJnX0jdld7vkcRYLPaENXUIgQ",
     "locationText": "Koblenz",
     "identifier": {
        "type": "MemberActivity",
        "id": "e9908afe-c9e1-11e5-829e-22000ae606bd"
     },
     "tags": {
        "itinerary": [
           "rhinegetaway"
        ],
        "season": [
           "spring"
        ],
        "cruise-itinerary": [
           "rhine-getaway"
        ],
        "_country": [
           "DE"
        ],
        "_city": [
           "lutzel"
        ]
     },
     "source": {
        "type": "ProjectActivity",
        "id": "54b97332-b9e4-11e3-876f-22000a240faf"
     },
     "valid": true
  },
  {
     "likes": 10,
     etc....

  }
}
```

Comment: You're casting an object to a string. What result are you expecting to see?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can get inside the "data" object and be able to display things like likes and the image objects into the DOM. However, right now when I try to loop through "data". It returns with [object Object]. I commented out my string so it should still be an object.

Comment: Your object contains nested objects, so several times `value` will not be a string but an object. If you output that, that is what you get. Also, you keep overwriting the text content in your loop, so only the last `value` is made visibible, which happens to be such nested object.

Comment: How would it be possible to get into those? I've tried JSON.parse(obj.data) and that either returns with a syntax error or it won't display anything.

Comment: Indeed `JSON.parse(obj.data)` does not make sense, since `obj.data` is not JSON, but a Javascript object. `JSON.stringify` might be useful depending on which output you expect.

Answer (score -1):

You are experiencing this issue because you are looping over array of object and for this purpose you have to use nested loops as follow (Replace your call back code with following function):

```
function callback(obj){
  $.each(obj.data, function(index, element){
      // this outer loop will iterate over each object in array
      $.each(element, function(key, value){
          // this inner loop will iterate over each value in object
          if(value instanceof Object){
             // element is object parse it accordingly
             // you can apply parse logic based on key; as each object is of different type.
          }else{
             $('.data').text(value);
          }
      });
  });
}
```

This loop will show all properties of an object you don't have to access individual property like `value.likes`. However, you have to write parser for the keys which have objects as their value. Obviously this is solution for showing all properties from object. In case you want access only few properties then drop inner loop and access those properties as `element.likes`.

Comment: Why did you marked this answer as down voted? I have exactly pointed out issue with your code and suggested possible fix. It's not fair.

Answer (score -1):

In your loop, `value` will still hold an object (one of the objects in the array that `data` is), and if you give that to `.text()`, you'll get `object Object` just like with any other object.

You can access the individual properties of that object in the loop:

```
$.each(obj.data, function(index, value){
    $('.data').text(value.likes); // etc.
})
```

As mentioned in a comment, this will overwrite the content of the `.data` element with every iteration, so will probably still not yield the expected result.

EDIT: If you want to display all likes, you'll have to assemble the string you want to display first, and then update your HTML.

```
var likes = [];

$.each(obj.data, function(index, value){
    likes.push(value.likes);
});

$('.data').text(likes.join(', '));
```

*This could of course be done "better" with `.reduce`, but that requires a more fundamental understanding of JS.*

Comment: I've tried that and it returns the the last like in the array. Is there a way to show all likes? Such as `$('.data').text(value.likes[index]);`?

Comment: @kirdua I've updated the answer to reflect this - you need to restructure your code a bit to achieve what you want.